# HttpUrlConnection time out after some time

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask to download images, which tends to work for some minutes and stop working after some time.

I need to know if there is a better way to resolve this problem

```
private void setupChart(String url){
    showAsyncIndicator();

    new DownloadImageTask(chartView).execute(url);

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Bitmap>{

    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage){
        this.bmImage = bmImage;

    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urlDisplay = urls[0];

        Bitmap mIcon = null;

        InputStream in;

        int responseCode ;

        try {
            URL  url = new URL(urlDisplay);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();

            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                in = connection.getInputStream();

                mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                in.close();



            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }

        return mIcon;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

        clearAsyncIndicator();
    }
}

private void showAsyncIndicator(){
    // doing someThings here later
}


private void clearAsyncIndicator(){
     // doing someThings here later
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details on what "stops working" means? Is there an exception? Does the code just exit without completing the download?

Comment: if i get on the screen the first time, everything works fine, but if I leave the phone on that screen for a few minutes that is when i observe the problem. I tried to log the responseCode but it look ok (200) and i did check if I'm getting the urls, that look great too. The problem looks wired to me.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is a http timeout error you can try  connection.setConnectTimeout(time); to change timeout but in any case I think that you should use Volley to get image, for me it's better solution...

http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

You can find easy a lot tutorial about it

Comment: I can't use external library for my project. Volley will be a good idea but is not the best choice for me. Thanks